# How do I get multiple objects to process things at the same time

Tags: c#

I have a C# form with a button, a timer and an ImageSearch class.

This button starts 6 objects(ImageSearch) that will do some image searching for me.

These 6 objects each individually update a picturebox on the main form.

When my button creates the objects and starts the timer, the timer will execute each objects crawl function.

My problem is they process one image at a time and not individually even though they are separate objects. How do I get them to run independently, make 6 timers?

I want all objects to run simultaneously.

When my form starts I create all 6 objects.

```
ImageSearch imageSearch1 = new ImageSearch(URL);
ImageSearch imageSearch2 = new ImageSearch(URL);
ImageSearch imageSearch3 = new ImageSearch(URL);
ImageSearch imageSearch4 = new ImageSearch(URL);
ImageSearch imageSearch5 = new ImageSearch(URL);
ImageSearch imageSearch6 = new ImageSearch(URL);
```

Then my button just starts the timers, Timer1 to timer6 to be enabled and sets the interval.

Timer1 for example:

```
imageSearch1.Crawl();
```

Comment: Without code it's hard to figure out what your timer is doing, in any case, a timer doesn't seem like a reasonable solution to the problem. Also, the image loading, if the image originates from the web, should be asynchronous, that is either wrapped in a task or thread.

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: I guess you will have to use multiple threads for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What would you need a timer for?

How about using Parallel LINQ instead:

```
imageSearchers
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(x => x.DoSomeThing());
```

PLINQ tries to use a sensible ammount of threads for this.

You could also use multiple `Task`'s:

```
        Task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => imageSearch1.Search());
        Task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => imageSearch2.Search());
        Task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => imageSearch3.Search());
        Task.WaitAll(new [] { Task1, Task2, Task3, ...})
```

Note: you don't need to wait "here" if you don't want to, but somewhere in your application you should keep track of async work, so that you can cancel it on shutdown / wait for it to end / handle exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using new Task API, something like:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for( var i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    tasks.Add( Task.Run( () => ImageSearch.Search( forImage ) ) );
Tasks.WaitAll( tasks.ToArray() );
```

This way, you offload all the scheduling and waiting to the framework, and focus on your business logic.